# Eclipse SVN Algorithm missing: No installed provider supports this key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, svnkit

In Eclipse I sometimes get the following error message in the console when starting an SVN-update or any other SVN-action:

```
update [myLocalSVNpath] -r HEAD --force
    svn: E175002: Algorithm missing:  
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '[myRemoteSVNpath]/trunk'
    svn: E175002: Algorithm missing:  
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '[myRemoteSVNpath]/trunk'
    Algorithm missing:  
    No installed provider supports this key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
    class configured for Mac (provider: SunJCE) cannot be found.
    com.sun.crypto.provider.HmacCore$HmacSHA384
```

Sometimes I can do some SVN operations (mostly update, compare, show history, commit) and then suddenly this message occurs and no SVN operations work any more. Restarting Eclipse or restarting the computer helps sometimes, not always.

I’m using a Windows 10 with Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0), Build id 20190314-1200 and „SVNKit Client Adapter“ in version 1.8.12.3. All other developers also use Windows 10 and a similar Eclipse version.

The workaround is to use Tortoise SVN in parallel so I can do SVN operations even if in Eclipse it doesn’t work.

**Short question**: How can I fix this?

**Detailled question**: Where does this missing class come from and where do I have to configure / install / add / exchange / remove the missing class? Or where (and how) can I install a provider that supports that asked key?

Comment: `com.sun.crypto.provider.HmacCore$HmacSHA384` is part of the Java runtime as is the `com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE` provider (at least on macOS).

Comment: Yes, also in JDK 1.8.0_181 on (my) Windows there is a `sunjce_provider.jar` with `com.sun.crypto.provider.HmacCore#HmacSHA384` in it.

Comment: It seems that this error only occurs when the VPN connection from my computer to the SVN repository is interrupted (or not connected at all). And if it occurs then the error stays and Eclipse will continue to show it.